# Building apjsua sample application of pjsip for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, voip, pjsip

I have followed [PJSIP](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) tutorial and I have successfully build **apjsua** sample application.

When I try to add account by +a it ask me for Sip Url, Url of the Registrar, Auth Realm, username, Password

I entered

- Sip Url : sip:140@122.252.232.5
- Registrar : sip:122.252.232.5
- Auth Realm : *
- Username : 140
- Password : example

After that it gave me following error

```
    10-17 19:57:27.165: I/apjsua(920): 19:57:27.165  sip_resolve.c  ...Failed to resolve '122.252.232.532.5'. Err=70018 (gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE))
10-17 19:57:27.174: I/apjsua(920): 19:57:27.174    tsx0x223a5c  ...Failed to send Request msg REGISTER/cseq=54907 (tdta0x1eb9a0)! err=70018 (gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE))
10-17 19:57:27.185: I/apjsua(920): 19:57:27.185    pjsua_acc.c  .....SIP registration failed, status=502 (gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE))
10-17 19:57:27.199: I/apjsua(920): 19:57:27.199    pjsua_acc.c  .....Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 2 in 6 seconds..
10-17 19:57:27.212: I/apjsua(920): 19:57:27.212      sip_reg.c  ..Error sending request, status=70018
10-17 19:57:27.226: I/apjsua(920): 19:57:27.226    pjsua_acc.c  ..Unable to create/send REGISTER: gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE) [status=70018]
```

Does any body know where I am getting wrong???

Or does anybody know any other way to use pjsip library for android???

Comment: I wonder how did you successfully build apjsua for android... the instructions seem to work with pjusa, but with apjusa, when I import the project into eclipse, I always get multiple errors in apjsua_app_wrap.c (unresolved inclusion errors, and Type 'JNIEnv' could not be resolved and many other errors... can you help me please?

Comment: Friend now when I am looking at the docs, everything is changed.You are right the docs are of pjsua, you can try building this. I would refer you to study the open source projects like CSipSimple, SIPDroid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're in luck. I was sitting with this problem a few days ago and it just looked like a simple initialization error. You should really get to grips with debugging c code else you're gonna have a hard time understanding the pjsip stack. Anyway here's what you do:

Make the "setInput" method under /pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/main_android.c look like this:

```
void setInput(char *s)
{
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(app_var.line); i++)
  {
      app_var.line[i]=NULL;
  }

  /* app_var.line[0] = 0; */

  if (strlen(s) < sizeof(app_var.line))
      strncpy(app_var.line, s, strlen(s));
  pj_sem_post(app_var.input_sem);
}
```

Looking at the code changes, you should be able to see that the app_var.line char variable was not being cleared properly. Now go to the /pjsip-apps/build/ folder and execute "make". Then go to the /pjsip-apps/src/apjsua/ folder and execute "make". Thereafter refresh your eclipse project and run. That should do the trick.

Comment: OMG................you are a life saver...........:) it just worked perfect......Thank You so much

Comment: Actually I have one another problem......the sample app apjsua does't start at first attempt. I have to run it 4-5 times after that it shows the content.....have you solved this problem also??????

Comment: Yeah I think I know what you mean... I did see the "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad" error a few times on startup. The app is referencing unused memory locations. I figure PJSIP should be started before anything is done so I changed the code at the end of the "onCreate" method in "ApjsuaActivity.java" file as follows:         PjsuaThread.finished = false;
        PjsuaThread pjsuaThread = new PjsuaThread();
        pjsuaThread.start();
        
        TextOutTask outTask = new TextOutTask();
        outTask.tv = tv;
        outTask.execute(); It seemed like it made a difference..

Comment: Don't worry about it dude...just glad to help. I'm trying to get to PJSUA's internals...like I wanna remove the UI and add a full "Phone" UI on top of it...not so easy but I'm trying. Let me know if you manage to do something similar. Cheers.

Comment: your above code also worked.......and now as i am able to register so i am also looking forward to change ui....and surely will get to u when i do so...... Thanks Again for your help :)

Comment: Hi Houston...I have managed to change ui by automating the commands for registration by using thread. this thread will run every command one by one needed for registration. would you like me to share some code??

Comment: Hi Maninder...I've also got round to doing a bit of ui stuff...basically I just ripped open that console_app_main loop to suit my requirements. In the loop I switch on a single variable which indicates what function I want to perform...like registration, make a call, send a message and so on. Changes in the ui affect the value of the variable I am switching on...similar to what pjsua is already doing. Sure lets see what you've done...

Comment: I am not able find any example named apjsua in currently updated code i received from SVN. is it the same pjsua sample ?

Comment: The PJSIP stack receives excellent support and development enhancements hence I wouldn't be surprised if a lot has changed. The sample application PJSUA is definitely in there...just gotta read the doc and figure it out.